# WPF: How to apply command to a context menu of a nested Listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am working on a wpf application using PRISM. This is my first ever WPF application and I have found myself in a situation where I can't go forward.

My scenario is this, I have a List of groups which I am binding with a ListBox, you can call it parent ListBox, each group object has a list of users associated to it and I am binding that list with another ListBox which is nested in the parent ListBox. Both bindings are working fine as you can see here:

[image]

I am facing two problems.

**1.** I can select both groups and individual users withing group separately but they are not synch, means If i select a user then the group which contains this user is not getting selected. I tried IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" but that doesn't seems to be working.

I would greatly appreciate if someone can point me out in a right direction how to achieve this or if there is any other way beside using ListBox within a ListBox.

**2.** I have a context menu associated with parent ListBox and I am able to successfully bind the commands with menus, but I am having troubles binding commands with nested ListBox Context Menu, here is my code

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstOfGroups" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentContest.Groups}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}"
             Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
             Background="Transparent" SelectionMode="Single"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             Height="400">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" Width="1200"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Add Contestant" Command="{Binding AddGroupCommand}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit Contestant" Command="{Binding EditGroupCommand}"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete Contestant" Command="{Binding DeleteGroupCommand}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            </ListBox>

<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate" >
        <Border x:Name="spPubItemBorder" Margin="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Background="Honeydew">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Name="tbGroupName" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextBox}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Group Name: {0}">
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Name="tbGroupAmount" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextBox}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Group Amount: {0}">
                            <Binding Path="Amount" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <!--<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ContestantList}"
                              AlternationCount="2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContestantTemplate}">

                </ItemsControl>-->
                <ListBox x:Name="lstOfContestant" Grid.Row="1"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ContestantList}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContestant, ElementName=lstOfGroups}"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContestantTemplate}"
                     Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleForContestant}"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyleForContestant}"
                     Background="Transparent" SelectionMode="Single"
                     Height="Auto">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" Width="375"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Add Contestant" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddContestantCommand,ElementName=contestantManager}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Edit Contestant" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditContestantCommand,ElementName=contestantManager}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete Contestant" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.DeleteContestantCommand,ElementName=contestantManager}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
                </ListBox>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I was wondering if someone can point me in a right direction here as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1, set the `IsSelected` property of the group ListBox to true if `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`

```
<Style x:Key="GroupListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This will set the group's `ListBoxItem` as Selected when the keyboard focus is anywhere within the `ListBoxItem`

As for #2, it sounds like you're getting the wrong item, probably because you're using `ElementName` in your binding, however the name is set on multiple items. Try using a `RelativeSource` binding to find the `ContextMenu` itself, then bind to the `PlacementTarget.DataContext`

```
<MenuItem Header="Add Contestant"
          Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.AddContestantCommand, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
              AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Rachel, adding the style triggers seems to have done the trick but I am still unable to bind commands to context menu with the code you provided above.

Comment: @user781466 The `PlacementTarget` will return whatever object has the `ContextMenu`, so be sure the `AddContestCommand` exists on that element's `DataContext`. You may need to do something hackish to get the correct `DataContext`, such as binding the `Tag` property of that element to the `DataContext` that has the command you want. I'd recommend using a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to figure out what the exact `DataContext` is that you're binding to

Comment: @user781466 Actually I just noticed your group `ListBox` is named `lstOfGroups` while your contestant ContextMenu items are binding to an `ElementName=contestantManager`. Try changing the `ElementName` to `lstOfGroups` first.

Comment: Thanks, although changing the ElementName to lstOfGroups didn't work but you have introduced a good tool, I am going to spend some time with it and try to figure out the DataContext of the nested ListBox.

Comment: @user781466 Glad I could help, goodluck with your project :) If my answer was useful to you, or if it answered your question, would you mind voting it up or accepting it by clicking the up arrow next to it, or the checkmark?